# Symfony2 & Doctrine2: Command loop creates new entity on each cycle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, command-line-interface

I have a Symfony2 CLI script running which should update a timestamp each 3 seconds.
The problem is: `$this->em->persist($processInfo)` creates a new entry in the DB each time it is executed. I want it to UPDATE, not to CREATE on each cycle.

```
$processInfo = new ....ProcessInfo();

while(true){
     $someObject = new ..();
     $this->em()->persist($someObject);

     $this->em()->clear(); // sorry forgot this line in my initial question

     $processInfo->setLastCheckOn($now); // to know if the script is still running, we set a timestamp in the db
     $this->em()->persist($processInfo);
     $this->em()->flush();


     sleep(3);
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `persist` only once. Then you need to commit the active transaction and start a new , in order to tell the database to save them and make a new transaction:

```
$processInfo = new ....ProcessInfo();
$this->em()->persist($processInfo);
$this->em()->getConnection()->commit();
while(true){
    $processInfo->setLastCheckOn($now); // to know if the script is still running, we set a timestamp in the db
    $this->em()->flush();
    sleep(3);
}
```

Comment: can you describe what you are doing here? this is far from intuitive. further I have some other code in the loop to- I have to make sure that there are no side effects...

Comment: @stoefln Removed unnecessary code. The problem is even though `flush` sent the queries to the database, symfony (or you) has already started a transaction somewhere in your code and no changes will be made until it's commited.  `while(true)` is an infinity loop in your code and the further code won't be executed, so the transaction will remain active. You need to commit it explicitly before while loop and let `flush` start another transaction.

Comment: you mean the latest version of doctrine2? no, and it's currently not possible to upgrade. will come back to you if i tested it with the most up to date version...

Comment: No i meant the last version of the code i edited. If the line `$this->em()->getConnection()->commit();` gives an error, then you haven't started a transaction and this line should be removed. Changes will be flushed without it. (I suppose setLastCheckOn is just a setter-method).

Comment: oh sorry so much, I forgot a line in my question. A very important one: $this->em()->clear() in the loop. Now it seems more logic for me too, that an object is created for each cycle. Problem is: I need that line to ensure that objects which are modified in the loop, are written to db immediately (concurrency: I am running multiple instances of the same script) 
So maybe I should open one connection for writing the logInfo and one connection for writing other objects?